# Drawing a PIE chart in C# MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-charts

I have created a ASP.NET C# MVC3 project, and i need to display a PIE chart and populate it with values returned by the following controller;

My Controller ;

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new TimeTrackerModel();
            model.TypeSchools = AllDataList.retrieveAlltypeSchool();
            return View(model);        

        }
```

The Model Type Schools will return the `number of Primary, Secondary and Tertiary Schools in UK`.

Now, i need to display these values in a `PIE chart`. How can draw a `PIE chart` according to the Values returned.

1.) How can i draw a PIE chart (I am unable to drag and drop the CHART tool from the toolbar)
2.) How can i populate the PIE chart with the values given from the controller.

Comment: I just googled your question : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/charts-for-Asp-Net-mvc-application/

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need js library for that purpose, I suggest [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com): http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

2) You may create custom view template for your model or simple view

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial that will show how to populate the values to the pie chart?

Comment: Check out page sources of the example from reply. You'll need to copy html markup (table structure) on your page and ask Raphael to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot drag and drop controls in mvc view pages.
And how the chart is returned from an controller is specific to the tools or library used.
There are numerous ways to draw chart:
Some are

1. Microsoft Chart : [MS Chart Samples from Code Project](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET&ei=8B5QUZHdJsuIrAfO6oDwCw&usg=AFQjCNHsmzhf0BEW8K2xJMuO8pjOAuJz2g&sig2=vojitS2oRGPP-Rr8D0Znew&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk)
2. pdfReport:[Also uses MS Chart](http://pdfreport.codeplex.com)
3. High Chart: [Highchart] but is not free for non-commercial use[3](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)
   Hence find their samples and documentations before selecting your best option.

Comment: You can only drag-n-drop HTML components and not Chart etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com) which is a very popular js library for producing charts. E.g. Bargraphs, plots, pie charts, etc.

I suggest you look at [Pie Charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) on jqplots website. They also give you clear examples.